# Fetching a specific object out of a python dictionary by matching against another object that compares equal

Tags: python, class, data-structures, collections, set

This is more a theoretical question than practical.

Suppose I have a Python set `s` filled with instances of some class C, where C has some custom equality relation. I also have on hand an instance `x` of C, and I know that there is an object `x'` in `s` such that `x == x`, although `id(x) != id(x')`.

How can I get a reference to the object `x'`?

Things I've tried already:

- `s & {x}` / `{x} & s`. In both cases, the expression evaluates to the object `x`. In the Python source for set intersection, if the sets to intersect are different sizes, the result set takes its objects from the smaller set.
- `s.pop()`, which gives me no control over which element is removed.

---

As motivation, `s` might be a cache of objects. Rather than storing duplicate instances of a class in memory, we'd rather reuse the instance we've already created. So we create the potentially-duplicate instance, check if we've created an identical instance before, and if so, use that instance instead.

I know that I can accomplish similar behaviour with a dictionary, but I'm specifically curious about whether it can be done with just the set interface.

Comment: I have convinced myself that this is not possible.